# Dynamically Div in DOJO

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo

I trying create dynamically div in DOJO, amount of divs is depends of value `count` 
Div must be insert under `<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" id="maintab" style="width:100%; height:100%;">`

My dynamically divs must looks like `<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-id="dtab" title="title" data-dojo-props="selected:false">` (in view it's  a bookmark)

My question is how make function with specific `data-dojo-type` , `id` and `title`
At the moment I have
`

```
function myFunction() {
var node = dojo.doc.getElementById('maintab');
node.appendChild += "<div data-dojo-type='dijit/layout/ContentPane' data-dojo-id='testTab' title='test' data-dojo-props='selected:false' >sample text</div>";
}
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is not valid DOM API usage.  `appendChild` is a function that you should be calling, and it receives a DOM node.  Applying string concatenation directly to `appendChild` makes no sense in that context (and concatenating `innerHTML`, which you are likely confusing it with, gets unwieldy very fast anyway).

Moreover, you are talking about dynamically adding declarative widget markup, but it would probably make a lot more sense and be a lot more direct to simply programmatically create each ContentPane.  Otherwise, you would also need to run the parser over the declarative markup after you build it.

It also doesn't make much sense to assign every child ContentPane to the same variable name, which is what you would be unwittingly doing by setting the same static `data-dojo-id` every time.

If `maintab` is already parsed and instantiated as a TabContainer, you could do something like the following (I'm assuming Dojo 1.6 or earlier style code since that is what you used above):

```
function addChild(title) {
    var container = dijit.byId('maintab');
    var child = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({ title: title });
    container.addChild(child);
    return child;
}
```

If the types of child widgets can also vary, you could pass that in too (this example also assumes you might want to pass in varying arguments for each):

```
function addChild(Constructor, args) {
    var container = dijit.byId('maintab');
    var child = new Constructor(args);
    container.addChild(child);
    return child;
}
// Usage e.g. addChild(dijit.layout.ContentPane, { title: 'Hello' })
```

If, for some reason, you really need/want to construct declarative HTML before the container is parsed, you could do something like the following:

```
function addChildMarkup(moduleId, argsString) {
    // Notice dojo.byId used here to retrieve DOM node
    // (vs. dijit.byId in earlier examples to retrieve widget instance)
    var container = dojo.byId('maintab');
    return dojo.create('div', {
        'data-dojo-type': moduleId,
        'data-dojo-props': argsString
    }, container);
}
// Usage: addChildMarkup('dijit.layout.ContentPane', '{ title: "Hello" }')
```